# Ubuntu 20.0.4 failing to boot after restore

Tags: boot, rsync

I recently swapped out my hard drive and used rsync to restore files from my previous hard drive after reinstalling the OS. The install was successful but after running rsync to restore the files, I'm getting an "error: no such device: <uuid_of_device>" message when trying to boot.

Does anyone know how this could be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: Which files were restored by rsync? All files? All files in /home/yourUserName/?

Comment: hi serafim
everything except for "lost+found" were restored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably overwritten the new `/etc/fstab` with the old one.
There are several ways to correct it but you can't be certain that it works. One way is as described by @waltinator but the easiest way is to

1. Boot from a Live USB stick.
2. Select “Install Ubuntu”.
3. Optionally, select to download updates and third-party software while
   installing. Click ‘Continue’.
4. The next step is important. Select "Reinstall Ubuntu" (probably followed
   by a version number). Click "Continue" or "Install Now" (I don't remember
   which).

Your system will be reinstalled without erasing any of your files.

Another option is to

1. Boot from your Live USB stick and select “Try Ubuntu”.
2. Open a terminal and
3. enter the command: sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
4. enter: sudo apt-get update
5. enter: sudo apt install boot-repair
6. Start boot-repair to repair grub, Select "Recommended repair"

This works if you don't have the old disk connected.

Answer (score 0):

In your `/etc/fstab`, you identify partitions by `UUID=...`. Your new disk has different Universal Unique IDentifiers.

Boot from a USB key, find the new UUIDs (`man parted lsblk`).

Mount your on-disk root filesystem, ensuring that it's Read/Write `rw`.

Edit `on-disk-root/etc/fstab` and plug in the new UUIDs.